# Make Script to automatically load m3u in VLC Network (MojaveOS)

Tags: vlc-media-player, iptv

So I'm tired of always having to open VLC / Open Network, copying & pasting my IPTV m3u network address to load.

Can someone help me (if possible) to create a script that will automatically open VLC and load my m3u without having to always copy & paste the link?

I know I can create a simple playlist with my m3u, but the problem is they either change around the channels and/or add/remove channels.

So by having an automatic script that would load and always load an up-to-date list would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

gui way

```
vlc http://link.to/playlist.m3u
```

or pure terminal

```
nvlc http://link.to/playlist.m3u
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I open VLC and load my m3u without having to always copy & paste the link?

Use one of the `[stream]` command line options. If you are using Windows you can change your VLC shortcut to include additional command line options.

```
Usage: vlc [options] [stream] ...
You can specify multiple streams on the commandline.
They will be enqueued in the playlist.
The first item specified will be played first.
```

...

```
Stream MRL syntax:

  [[access][/demux]://]URL[#[title][:chapter][-[title][:chapter]]]
  [:option=value ...]

  Many of the global --options can also be used as MRL specific :options.
  Multiple :option=value pairs can be specified.

URL syntax:
  file:///path/file              Plain media file
  http://host[:port]/file        HTTP URL
  ftp://host[:port]/file         FTP URL
  mms://host[:port]/file         MMS URL
  screen://                      Screen capture
  dvd://[device]                 DVD device
  vcd://[device]                 VCD device
  cdda://[device]                Audio CD device
  udp://[[<source address>]@[<bind address>][:<bind port>]]
                                 UDP stream sent by a streaming server
  vlc://pause:<seconds>          Pause the playlist for a certain time
  vlc://quit                     Special item to quit VLC
```

Source [VLC command-line help - VideoLAN Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)

If you are able to use shell scripts then you can use the following script and modify it to your specific requirements:

> ```
> if [[ "$1" == "" ]] ; then
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> DUMMY=""
>
> # location of playlist
> PLAYLIST=/tmp/playlist.m3u
>
> ### the playlist is only updated from the Freebox if the playlist file does 
> ### not exist
> ###   simply remove the playlist file given by the location $PLAYLIST 
> ###   to force an update the next time the script is called
> if [[ ! -f $PLAYLIST ]] ; then
>     RAWPLAYLIST=`mktemp`
>     echo "recovering Playlist"
>     wget -q http://mafreebox.freebox.fr/freeboxtv/playlist.m3u -O $RAWPLAYLIST
> ### the following trick is found from:
> ### http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207354/how-to-remove-all-of-the-diacritics-from-a-file
> ### and allows to replace accent characters by non-accent characters
>     iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT $RAWPLAYLIST > $PLAYLIST
>     \rm $RAWPLAYLIST
> fi
>
> COMMAND="grep -v rtsp $PLAYLIST | grep -v EXTM3U "
> for i in $@ ; do
>     if [[ $i == "-dummy" ]] ; then
>         DUMMY=dummy
>     else
>         COMMAND=$COMMAND" | grep -i "$i
>     fi
> done
>
> COMMAND=$COMMAND" | head -1"
>
> FLINE=`mktemp`
> eval $COMMAND > $FLINE
> LINE=`cat $FLINE`
>
> N=`grep -xn -f $FLINE $PLAYLIST | cut -d : -f 1`
>
> \rm $FLINE
>
> N=$((N + 1))
> LINK=`head -n $N $PLAYLIST | tail -1`
>
> if [[ "$LINE" == "" ]] ; then
>     echo "No matching channel found"
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> echo "Opening vlc for: $LINE"
> echo $LINK
>
> if [[ "$DUMMY" == "" ]] ; then
>     vlc "$LINK" --network-caching=1500 --no-loop
> fi
> ```
>
> You save it in a place in your PATH (maybe in your private bin folder:
>   `~/bin/` if this is in your PATH ) for example as `FB_VIEW.sh`, you
>   make it executable by `chmod +x FB_VIEW.sh`.
>
> Then the simple use is:
>
> ```
> FB_VIEW.sh "list of patterns"
> ```
>
> to start the first channel in the playlist that contains these
>   patterns (order is not important between subpatterns separated by a
>   space). The pattern list may contain the word "-dummy" in which case
>   only the found channel and rtsp link is shown but vlc is not actually
>   started. The pattern match is not case sensitive. You may also use the
>   programm number of channel as pattern but on the Freebox you may have
>   different fluxes (Adsl, TNT, HD, standard, bas-debit) for the same
>   number and you may need to add a second pattern such as HD or TNT to
>   select the right TV flux.
>
> In this version the first time you start the script it will download
>   the playlist from the Freebox (using wget), replace the accented
>   characters by non-accented characters and store it in the default
>   location /tmp/playlist.m3u (I found the trick for this yesterday).
>   When you want later to force an update of the playlist you simply
>   remove the existing file and the update will be done the next time the
>   script is called (this takes about 1-2 seconds). Note that Free
>   applies regularly certain (typically modest) changes on the playlist.
>
> You can easily modify the name/default location of the playlist and
>   also remove the "update-part" (if you don't like it) in which case you
>   have to provide the playlist manually in the appropriate location.

Source [Play specific item in m3u playlist !? - The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=133297)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Using VLC as an IPTV receiver - The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=65728)